# pandas.get_dummies on float numbers for machine learning

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in the form of a panda dataframe that has the columns watercolor (string), place (string), temperature(float).

I want to use one hot encoding to turn the data into categories like

```
color: darkblue, lightblue, teal
        1           0        0
        0           1        0
```

For the strings it is no problem, but how do I set the intervals for the temperature(float)?

I tried writing:

```
output = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))
```

The problem is that all the unique float values are turned into a separate category like:

```
temperature:   37,6 37,7  37,9  38
                0     1    0     0
                1     0    0     0
```

That means that my program will overfit the data since all the temperatures are turned into separate categories. I would like to specify the interval for the third column(temperature). So I want to group all values from say 37,5-39 and from 39-41,5 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

try use `cut` before creating the dummies columns

```
pd.cut(df['temperature'], [37.5, 39, 41,.....], labels=['37.5-39', '39-41',.....])
```